# Получение данных из либы без потери vfptr после unload

Tags: c++, qt, dll

Имеется крупный проект, разбитый на либы. Во многих либах используется одна структура, описанная в общем хедере.
В самой структуре некоторые подструктуры имеют базовые классы, в которые инкапсулированы общие для этих подструктур поля.
Одна из либ имеет некоторую сложную логику формирования этой структуры, и я хочу ею воспользоваться. Для этого я загружаю либу, используя `QLibrary` и запрашиваю у неё нужную мне структуру.

Описание структуры максимально упрощено до самого важного - базового класса и его наследника:
ParserStruct.hpp

```
class Base {
    public:
        virtual ~Base() = default;

        int justVal = 0;
};

class Derivative : public Base {};
```

Код либы:
StructPlaceholder.hpp

```
#include "../ParserStruct.hpp"
#include <QtCore/QtGlobal>
#include <QVector>

extern "C" Q_DECL_EXPORT void structFilling( QVector<Derivative> &d );
```

StructPlaceholder.cpp

```
#include "StructPlaceholder.hpp"

void structFilling( QVector<Derivative> &d ) {
    d.push_back( Derivative() );
}
```

Далее код, в котором я загружаю либу и прошу один из её методов заполнить структуру:
main.cpp

```
#include "LibLoader.hpp"
#include "../ParserStruct.hpp"
#include <QVector>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QVector<Derivative> d;
    { //Этот скоуп ограничивает область жизни объекта libLoader, обладающего 
            //ресурсом QLibrary
        LibLoader libLoader( "Libka" ); //RAII, грузим либу в конструкторе и разгружаем 
            //её в деструкторе
        using structFilling = void(*)( QVector<Derivative> & );
        auto structFillingFun = libLoader.getFun<structFilling>( "structFilling" );

        structFillingFun( d );
    } /* При выходе из этого скоупа, для объекта libLoader будет вызван деструктор, 
         в котором, для ресурса QLibrary, будет вызван `unload`
      */

    /* Сейчас либа отгружена. Далее, когда для `d` будет вызван деструктор, он 
       будет вызван и для содержащихся в нём объектов, однако, после отгрузки либы,
       vfptr указывает на неинициализированную область памяти
    */
} //Будет вызван деструктор для `d` и его элементов, что приведёт к ошибке
```

Я не стал приводить код `LibLoader`, он крупный, и не делает ничего особо интересного. Если в нём возникнет нужда - приведу.

Собственно, **проблема** описана в комментарии, но продублирую:

Имеется класс `LibLoader`, в качестве его ресурса выступает объект `QLibrary`, для которого, в деструкторе `LibLoader` будет вызван метод `unload`.
Когда либа будет разгружена, `__vfptr` объектов, что были сформированы в этой либе, будут указывать на какую то неинициализированную область памяти (я понимаю это так - эти объекты указывают на таблицы, сформированные внутри загруженной либы, а когда либа разгружена, и указывать не на что)

[image]

Когда для объекта `d`, содержащего объект с `__vfptr`, будет вызван деструктор, деструктор должен быть вызван и для содержащихся в нём объектов, но теперь мы не имеем указателя на таблицу виртуальных методов, соответственно не можем вызвать нужный деструктор, а это приводит к падению программы.

Какие пути решения данной проблемы есть?
Пока в голову приходит лишь вариант держать либу загруженной до тех пор, пока не завершим работу с объектом `d`, после чего почистить его и после разгрузить либу, но такой вариант является крайне нежелательным.

Comment: Естественно, выгружать можно будет только после того, как не осталось ни одного живого объекта, ее использующего.

Comment: @VTT и нет никаких путей обхода? Скажем принудительная подмена `__vdptr` на ликвидный для текущего... не знаю, пространства?

Comment: Подмена на что? Деструктор-то так и остался в выгруженной библиотеке. Непонятно, отчего вообще возникает такое затруднение. Что вам мешает держать библиотеку загруженной пока она используется?

Comment: @VTT идея заключалась в использовании той же структуры из имеющегося заголовочного, общего для всех либ, но чем больше об этом думаю, тем менее разумным мне это кажется. Хорошо, спасибо за ответ, буду выгружать либу после завершения работы с структурой.

Comment: Так может имеет смысл сделать еще одну библиотеку именно для этой структуры?

Comment: @VTT слишком много зависимостей от этой структуры и её подструктур, к месту и не к месту, соответственно слишком много правок, на которые время не выделят, увы. Подумаю что с этим можно сделать. Спасибо